# What is the read?

Tags: grammar

1. What is the read/reading on the thermometer?

The answer would be 25c.

What form is correct for this question, read or reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reading" is correct. You need a noun here, and "read" is very rarely used as a noun.